# Wacom tablet not reconnecting when re-plugged

Tags: 14.04, usb, tablet, wacom

On 14.04, when plugging in a Wacom tablet the first time since reboot, it works. This appears in /var/log/syslog:

```
Oct 11 14:31:34 epicurus kernel: [122653.356109] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
Oct 11 14:31:34 epicurus kernel: [122653.450885] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=056a, idProduct=00b8
Oct 11 14:31:34 epicurus kernel: [122653.450895] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Oct 11 14:31:34 epicurus kernel: [122653.450900] usb 1-1.2: Product: PTK-440
Oct 11 14:31:34 epicurus kernel: [122653.450905] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Tablet
Oct 11 14:31:34 epicurus mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
Oct 11 14:31:34 epicurus mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Oct 11 14:31:34 epicurus kernel: [122653.777615] input: Wacom Intuos4 4x6 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/input/input17
Oct 11 14:31:34 epicurus kernel: [122653.778439] usbcore: registered new interface driver wacom
Oct 11 14:31:34 epicurus kernel: [122653.858674] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
Oct 11 14:31:34 epicurus kernel: [122653.907632] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
Oct 11 14:31:34 epicurus kernel: [122653.907635] usbhid: USB HID core driver
```

If I unplug the tablet, and re-plug it, it does not work. This time only the following lines appear in syslog:

```
Oct 11 15:11:19 epicurus kernel: [125025.451702] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
Oct 11 15:11:19 epicurus kernel: [125025.546319] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=056a, idProduct=00b8
Oct 11 15:11:19 epicurus kernel: [125025.546329] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Oct 11 15:11:19 epicurus kernel: [125025.546335] usb 1-1.2: Product: PTK-440
Oct 11 15:11:19 epicurus kernel: [125025.546340] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Tablet
Oct 11 15:11:19 epicurus kernel: [125025.548353] input: Wacom Intuos4 4x6 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/input/input22
Oct 11 15:11:19 epicurus mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
Oct 11 15:11:19 epicurus mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 9 was not an MTP device
```

I have tried to `rmmod wacom` etc... but nothing brings it back, except a reboot.

Note: **No longer experiencing this problem since switching to a newer laptop and new OS (Ubuntu 16.04) - same tablet.**

Comment: I've exaclty the same issue on Centos 7.4 right now...

Comment: @KevinLemaire  No longer experiencing this problem since switching to a newer laptop and new OS (Ubuntu 16.04) - same tablet. The old Laptop was an ASUS the new is a Thinkpad, although I suspect the either the USB subsystem or the kernel was what made the difference.